# Action for execute cloud script (push notification) dont work in segment

Tags: unity-game-engine, notifications, playfab

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQ8YP.png)

Action for execute cloud script (push notification) dont work in segment

Comment: Is you script not being triggered or the script is not doing what you expected?

Comment: the script is not being fired